# If I never battle in Clash of Clans and I have zero trophies will I get atacked at a higher townhall?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My question is will I get attacked after a while playing Clash of Clans from 0 trophies going to a higher town hall, because I have started a new game just need to learn some tricks and tips.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Could you give an example scenario?

Answer (score 1):

**You will get attacked only by players with similar trophy count.**

This means, theoretically you can get attacked by a higher level town hall than level 1 even if you have 0 trophies, but only if the attacking player also has a very low trophy count.

This can be useful even at higher trophy counts - if you start losing trophies on purpose, you will meet bases that are easier to beat.